# Remove leading '0' from a char and update the table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with ids they read '0050001B' and such then there is '50001B'. They are both the same but due to the fact that I'm using char when I want to return something it sees both as two different ids. Is there anyway to update the table such that I can get rid of the leading zero.
I used this code below to output without leading zeros, but I want to fix the table.

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM id) FROM mytable;
```

but i want to fix the table so the zeros are gone on the table, not just on the output.

any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `update`.

```
update mytable
set id =  TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that